# Telosys code generation fails when the table has foreign key

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, code-generation, telosys

I have a issue when generating code using Telosys.

After configuring all the information, when I click on **Create model**

[image: DB configuration]

I get the following issue:

[image: Create model issue]

If I remove foreign key from table and click **Create model** then this works fine.

It has become like have to remove the foreign key from table and Create model and then add back the foreign key again.

How to do this without removing foreign key constraint?

**PS**: I just use this tool to create Spring JPA entity.

Comment: which version of telosys are u using?

Comment: could you provide the SQL used to create the Foreign Key and the name of the table referenced by the FK ?

Answer (score 2):

After looking in the source code it seems that the table name referenced by the FK is not found in the model.

May be due to upper case / lower case difference in the table name. For example a FK referencing the "Foo" table instead of "FOO" (or vice versa).

You can check the table names retrieved from the database with "Get tables" in the "Meta-data" tab. Use "Get foreign keys" to check the Foreign Keys :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you skipped configuration. You can customize existing templates in order to generate jpa DAO

the templates available on GitHub : [https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3](https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/java7-persistence-spring-data-jpa)